# Best practice to perform query-string based search on the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a search page which includes a data list and a pannel to either perform search by keywords or by filtering criteria (something similar to http://shutr.bz/KpZk2p)

I have wrapped the data-list inside a `<contentTemplate>` and registered the search button as `<trigger>`, so when somebody either enters a keyword or filter's by criteria and click on button, the system build a query based upon the entered values, query database and load data-list, everything works perfect, BUT

Now there is a change in business requirement where I need to make this search a query string based search, so if one user have filtered down the data (building the search filter) then user can share the results with the subordinates just sharing the URL.

I know this needs something like `response.redirect` on button click and passing the entered values queryString and then read the URL on page load for the passed values.

Well I really looking for a best mechanism to implement this, since the data-list displays the images from DB and hence needs to be a quicker and effective.

Suggestions would be highly appreciable.

Thanks a lot on advance.

Comment: what I do not understand is that: The page you give us is working good and cool, do you ask how to make it like this page, or how to make it different and with more ajax (with out redirect) ?

Comment: @Aristos : I had been asked to rewrite the page using the querystring based query a manual one without Ajax, so everytime somebody pass values and click search the values are visible and passed by with the URL, so that that if one user want to share his searched result with another, he can just copy the URL and send.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Navigation project that will help you, http://navigation.codeplex.com/.

On the documentation page, http://navigation.codeplex.com/documentation, I go through building a sample that does exactly what you want. It uses ASP.NET Ajax with Ajax History support to provide bookmarking.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, actually I am working on Web Pages instead of web forms and the site already follow's an hierarchie, so I wouldn't be able to change the structure, expecting much of an work around with the querystring and response header.

Thanks for taking taking out time.